# Function that takes an async callback and puts it in a FuturesUnordered queue

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Below is code that does exactly what I want but fails on type checking. I’m guessing that it involves `Pin`, `Box`, and `dyn`.

Is this possible?

```rust
use async_stream::stream;
use futures::stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};

pub fn map<U, V, W>(
    f: impl Fn(&U) -> W,
    items: Vec<U>,
) -> impl futures::Stream<Item = V>
where
    V: Send,
    W: futures::Future<Output = V> + Send,
{
    stream! {
        let mut futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
        let mut i = 2;
        if 2 <= items.len() {
            futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(&items[0])));
            futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(&items[1])));
            while let Some(result) = futures.next().await {
                let y = result.unwrap();
                yield y;
                futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(&items[i])));
                i += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    async fn f(x: &u32) -> u32 {
        x + 1
    }
    let input = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let output = map(f, input);
    futures::pin_mut!(output);
    while let Some(x) = output.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

The exact error is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:40:18
   |
40 |     let output = map(f, input);
   |                  ^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<for<'_> fn(&u32) -> impl futures::Future<Output = u32> {f} as FnOnce<(&u32,)>>::Output`
              found associated type `<for<'_> fn(&u32) -> impl futures::Future<Output = u32> {f} as FnOnce<(&u32,)>>::Output`
   = note: the required lifetime does not necessarily outlive the empty lifetime
```

I have tried *many* variants of changing lifetimes, adding annotations of variations on `Box` and `Pin`, and applying compiler suggestions. Rather than hacking, I'm trying to understand whether it is even possible to write code that performs this logic.

My mental model has been that Rust cannot be convinced of the safety of references, so some object needs to be boxed in order to give Rust constant (pinned) access to it. I've been trying to figure out which object(s).

As requested by @Chayim Friedman, one of the exact solutions I tried was to set the signature of `map` to the following.

```rust
pub fn map<U, V>(
    f: impl Fn(&U) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = V> + '_>>,
    items: Vec<U>,
) -> impl futures::Stream<Item = V>
where
    V: Send,
```

The problem was that rust still complains about `tokio::spawn` not being sendable:

```rust
error[E0277]: `dyn futures::Future<Output = V>` cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:21:26
    |
21  |             futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(&items[0])));
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn futures::Future<Output = V>` cannot be sent between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `dyn futures::Future<Output = V>`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `Unique<dyn futures::Future<Output = V>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = V>>`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = V>>>`
```

Comment: Please state what you tried and what errors you get, and also what you understand from them.

Comment: Done. It would take a *very* long time to explain everything I've tried.

Comment: Then only explain key attempts that you tried because you expected them to work under your mental model, not everything you tried in a hope it'll work.

Comment: Ok, will this lead to a solution?

Comment: With your previous question you hit a corner case of the language. Maybe Rust has more, but any language has some. Now you just post the same code. What did you do with the answer I gave to your previous question? I can provide a working code pretty easily, but I don't want to write the code for you, I want to explain.

Comment: Specifically, when you applied my suggestion in my answer, what error did you get? Do you understand them, and their reasons?

Comment: I have literally put a box around ever single object in the signature. I understand that there needs to be a box because Rust can't be convinced of the safety of the references when async can hold them indefinitely.

Comment: I gave you a concrete signature. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I pasted it in exactly. The error I got complained that "checked the `Output` of this `async fn`, found opaque type". I probably pasted it wrong. I have no idea even what an opaque type is. Was this in a section of the book I missed?

Comment: An opaque type is `impl Trait`. But this is exactly what I told to show us, the attempts and their failures, with as much explanation as you can do.

Comment: There are literally dozens of different tries with multiple errors for each. I suspect I am falling into the SO trap of posting a lot of information and then nothing comes of it. I will continue adding info. Is the core logic not sufficient?

Like in Haskell, one might think the process is to figure out the outline of what needs to be done and then there is a specific solution of how to do it in a type-compatible way.

Comment: In Rust you're better think first about ownership, not algorithms.

Comment: Ok, I have posted the information you requested. Are you able to explain why this is failing? It's not just me that these errors are very hard to understand.

Comment: I think this is the part where after I posted a lot of information the OP disappears.

Comment: After all that, as it turns out is IS impossible.

Comment: Why are you desperately trying to use references? I think references are just conceptually wrong here and make things super complicated. If you pass a reference into a `tokio::spawn` you need to somehow tell Rust that you keep the original object alive until the spawned task is finished. Which is impossible, because the spawned task does not get cancelled if its `JoinHandle` gets dropped; Even if the entire stream gets cancelled, your `tokio::spawn` tasks still exist. And devinitely have dangling references. So your general approach to this problem is wrong, I'm afraid, if you use references.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that after a LOT of going down the wrong way. The previous answers suggested that if I used Pin<Box<dyn ...>>> it would work.

Comment: I think even `Pin<Box<dyn ...>>>` is way overkill. Just use plain old move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `Pin`, `Box`, or even references, for that matter.

You *own* the `Vec`, so just take elements out of it via move. That transfers the ownership of the elements to the `f` callback, which makes ownership management a *lot* easier.

```rust
use async_stream::stream;
use futures::stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};

pub fn map<U, W>(f: impl Fn(U) -> W, items: Vec<U>) -> impl futures::Stream<Item = W::Output>
where
    W: futures::Future + Send + 'static,
    W::Output: Send,
{
    stream! {
        // Convert into a fused iterator. Fused iterators
        // are guaranteed to return `None` continuously after
        // their last item.
        let mut iter = items.into_iter().fuse();
        let mut futures = FuturesUnordered::new();

        if let Some(el) = iter.next() {
            futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(el)));
        }
        if let Some(el) = iter.next() {
            futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(el)));
        }

        while let Some(result) = futures.next().await {
            let y = result.unwrap();
            yield y;

            if let Some(el) = iter.next() {
                futures.push(tokio::spawn(f(el)));
            }
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    async fn f(x: u32) -> u32 {
        x + 1
    }
    let input = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let output = map(f, input);
    futures::pin_mut!(output);
    while let Some(x) = output.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

```
2
3
4
```

I had to rewrite parts of your code because your version didn't have a stop criterium. It would always just crash by running out-of-bounds on the array access.

Comment: @Test removed redundant generic parameter and simplified code by introducing `fuse()`.